# Are there any references for acoustic measurements of Finnish consonants?

Tags: phonetics

I'd like to know details about the specific acoustic properties of Finnish consonants, as well as how these change in specific coarticulatory environments. It seems to be easier to find information about the vowels, for which formant measurements are readily available.